# How to download a file from website without link using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, browser-automation

References: [Class name of that file in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4h46.png) , [Excel file to be downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugEuy.png)

Friends, I'm trying to download the excel file from this world bank org website - https://www.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/procurement/debarred-firms

I'm trying to download it with automating the task by python script by using selenium library.

I've tried using XPath, Class and CSS selector methods.. but no luck in identifying the solution. Kindly have a look in below code which i'm tried and advise me your knowledge friends.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--log-level=OFF")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

try:
    #driver.get('https://www.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/procurement/debarred-firms');
    #downloadcsv= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="k-debarred-firms"]/div[1]/a');
    #gotit= driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "dialog_form_actions");
    #gotit.click();
    #Click on Download Button
    #driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="k-debarred-firms"]/div[1]/a').click()
    #time.sleep(50)

    driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/procurement/debarred-firms'})
    WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
'title="Excel"'))).click()

    driver.close()
    print("file downloaded")

except:
    print("Invalid URL")`
```

Comment: If you look at the HTML source on that website, is the link a javascript link?  When you download the file manually with the debugging console open, is there a stable URL for the file?

Comment: The link you provided access only the site. Where is the information about the file itself? Please, provide more details about what you want as the link of the file, for example, or describe the path you have to do to get the file manually.

Comment: @AndreCarneiro this is the URL we need to get the excel file from -- https://www.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/procurement/debarred-firms

File name: Sanctioned individuals and firms.xlsx

Comment: @PaulProgrammer no buddy.. there is no separate URL or link for downloading that excel file.

Comment: Even though, put more detail about what you're doing next time. It's the best thing you can do and helps a lot.

Comment: It looks like there is javascript that is converting the HTML table into a excel download.  Because it's not a real file download, it's unlikely to be able to download using a non-javascript aware tool.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay! I found your elements! But the the things are not so simple as a 'click'. The anchor/link is not "clickable", probably because some nasty Javascript is doing nasty things and you'll have to find out what is going on.

Anyways, I hope this code below helps somehow:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--log-level=OFF")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

try:
    driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/procurement/debarred-firms'})
    # WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'title="Excel"'))).click()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 500)
    # Waiting for the searching input text
    text = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "category")))
    print("INPUT TEXT FOUND: ", str(text.get_attribute('outerHTML')))
    # waiting for the download anchor/link
    download_anchor = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/a")))
    print("DOWNLOAD_ANCHOR: ", str(download_anchor.get_attribute('outerHTML')))

    download_anchor.click()

except Exception as e:
    print("Error: " + str(e))
finally:
    driver.close()
```

Check out the error message! Probably there some new clues there.

Comment: Thankyou for sharing all, that really helped lot in knowing errors :) i have tried with javascript execute function instead click() , but still unbale to download that file.. any idea here?

 # download_anchor.click()

    # WebElement webElement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(tabId)));
    # JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    # executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", download_anchor);

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",download_anchor)